# Programmatically set bitmap in layer list Android

Tags: android, bitmap, icons

I need programmatically set different icons in layer list by @+id/calendar_day_bottom_icon

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_date_today_bg"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/calendar_day_bottom_icon" >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_journal"
            android:gravity="bottom|center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In code I do next thing

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) cellView.getBackground();          
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_calendar_journal_reminder);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.calendar_day_bottom_icon, drawable);
```

But icon inserts incorrectly.

I want this one:
[image]

But there is: [image]

Comment: use bottom instead of bottom|center.

Comment: android:gravity="bottom|center" to android:gravity="bottom"

Comment: it doesn't work :((( any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution with another drawable file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_journal" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

get drawable

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.calendar_layers);
```

get LayerDrawable, get layer item and set it to another LayerDrawable.

```
LayerDrawable cellLayerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) cellView.getBackground();
Drawable drawable = layerDrawable.getDrawable(0);                    
cellLayerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.calendar_day_bottom_icon, drawable);
```